# Python - Spread across requests session object in class methods

Tags: python, python-requests

I'd like to spread across a requests session object across the class methods of my own class in order to reuse the same session for making requests by the object of my class.

Here is my current approach:

```
import requests

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = requests.Session()
        headers = {'key': 'value'}

    def method1(self):
        s = self.s
        s.get(url, headers=self.headers)
        s.post(url, headers=self.headers)
                     .
                     .
        return something

    def method2(self, something):
        s = self.s
        something = something
        s.get(url, headers=self.headers)
        s.post(url, headers=self.headers)
                     .
                     .

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myclass = MyClass()
    something = myclass.method1()
    myclass.method2(something)
```

Do you think this one is good enough? Are there any better ways to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change `s = requests.Session()` to `self.s = s = requests.Session()` to set the `Session` as both an attribute and as a local variable in case you need to use it again in `__init__`.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. Thank you for pointing it out, and I have edited it.  I think self.s = requests.Session() works nicely. What do others think?